# Android dual website / app support using IntentFilter's

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an android app that has some slimmed down functionality of my full website, such that when registering IntentFilter's, I limit the paths that the app supports.  eg.

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="*mysite.com" />
    <data android:path="/" />
    <data android:path="/login" />
    <data android:pathPrefix="/profile/" />
</intent-filter>
```

This works mostly well, so that in emails sent to users, only relevant links will direct them to the app.

However, I run into issues when explicitly going to my site in Chrome on Android, where the site has a login screen that looks something like:

```html
<form role="form" method="post" action="/login/" >
   ...
   <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

When I click the button, it asks me where I want to open the link, in the browser or in the app, since I also support "/login/" as an Android IntentFilter.  I would have assumed that by using relative paths for links within my site, it wouldn't have this behavior and would remain in the browser when initiated from the browser, but wrongfully so it seems.

So my question is, how can I support both an app and a website?  Even if the app supports all possible urls that the website also supports, it's terrible user experience to be prompted every time they click a link on the website after explicitly going to the browser.  Is there a different intent-filter setting I should be using?  How do apps/sites like twitter stay in the browser once I've opened it there, yet also detect new links and question where I want to open them?